# A request for a complex JUnit test example

Tags: java, android, unit-testing, junit

I am trying to write a suite of JUnit tests for an Android project. For each class that I have written I have a corresponding Test that is extending TestCase. In each of these TestCases I am under the impression that I should write a test() for each  in the class being tested. With that said I do not know how to go about testing methods that deal with multiple possible inputs. I would like to request some examples of testing complex methods that are more complex than the usual tutorial examples.

```
    public void tutorialTestExample() throws Exception {
    final int expected = 1;
    final int actual = 5;
    assertEquals(expected, actual);
}
```

Here is a method I am trying to test.

```
    public void distributeStones(int stones, int trayIndex) {
    if(stones == 0){
        switchPlayer();
    }
    while (stones > 0) {
        if (trayIndex == 15) {
            trayIndex = 0;
        } else {
            trayIndex++;
            if (board.get(trayIndex).getPlayer() == opponent && board.get(trayIndex).isStore() ) {
                trayIndex = IncrementTrayIndex(trayIndex);
            }
        }
        if (stones == 1 && board.get(trayIndex).getPlayer() == currentPlayer && board.get(trayIndex).isStore()){
            stones--;
            board.get(trayIndex).incrementStones();
            switchPlayer();
        }else if (stones == 1 && board.get(trayIndex).getStones() == 0 && board.get(trayIndex).getPlayer() == currentPlayer && !board.get(trayIndex).isStore()){
            stones--;
            stealStones(trayIndex);
        }else{
            stones--;
            board.get(trayIndex).incrementStones();
        }
    }
}
```

distributeStones moves stones around a game board that is represented as a List of Containers(both Stores and Trays).
What would you test for?
How can an assertion be used to test several possible outcomes dependent on the input?

Thank you for your time,
Chris

Comment: You can only test things which you can observe: return values, exceptions, changes of state on the instance of the class under test, calls made to methods on depended-upon objects. What do you need to test?

Comment: This feels off topic, too broad and/or asking for off site resources. I think you need to narrow it down. Try googling for some tutorials then seeing if you can make the question more specific.

Comment: I'd like to see an example of some more complex method tests if  possible?

Comment: Look for some tutorials on "parameterized tests", which might help with your specific "distributeStones" method.